# Assigning a value by default, allowing user to change it

Tags: php, button, input

I currently have a system in which the users, employees, check boxes (radio buttons), to let the employer know whether they are available (value=1) or unavailable (value=2) on certain dates.

```
echo '<ul id="datumselectie">';
echo '<li class="demo"><span class="beschikbaar"></span><span class="onbeschikbaar"></span>    </li>';

while ($datum <= $data) {
echo '<li class="' .strftime('%A',$datum). '">';                
echo strftime('%A %e %B %Y',$datum);
echo '<input type="radio" name="data[' .strftime('%Y-%m-%d',$datum). ']" value="1" />';
echo '<input type="radio" name="data[' .strftime('%Y-%m-%d',$datum). ']" value="0" />';
```

I would like to change the working of the system in such a way that for the coming two weeks the value of data is set to 1 by default, whilst giving the user the option to change the value to 0 up to a week before the actual date.

Could someone help me out here?

Comment: what is the specific question? WHat have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: Your question is way too vague, also don't print your HTML with echo like that... http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you need a simple DATEDIFF to determine which radio should be selected:

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
```

Once that's determined, you just need to write the appropriate button with the 'checked' tag:

```
echo '<input type="radio" name="data[' .strftime('%Y-%m-%d',$datum). ']" value="1" checked />';
```

Adding one more thing, as per the comments...
If you wanted to set this in the database, you need to know the SQL line.  Assuming, of course, you are using mySQL.

To set a value, depending on a range, it looks like this:

```
UPDATE [tablename] set defaultValue = 1 where [inputDate] between ([startDate] and [endDate]);
```

Just set your values there.  You need the starDate to be today and your endDate to be two weeks from now.  You do that in the PHP:

```
<?php
echo "Today is " . date("Y/m/d") . "<br>";

$date = new DateTime(date("Y/m/d"));
$date->modify('+14 days');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
?>
```

You'll have to do the rest of the coding yourself, but that's the basic idea.
Also, do a quick search on how mysqli works to get the exact syntax for your PHP code to execute this on your server.

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem, I want the value in the database to be 1 by default, whilst allowing the user to change it to 0. I figured that after setting it to 1 by default, I get rid of the first radio button, and change the second radio button to make it a regular button with which the changes can be made.

Comment: Well, you never said anything about the database in you question.  So, really, how was I supposed to know that?!  Someone please upvote.  That was undeserved.

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer in the phrasing of my original question, I didn't down vote you.

Comment: Well, someone did. And that pisses me off. Anyway, in the future, you must include WHERE you want that default to be set. As it stands, my answer to your OP is correct.  (And now that appears to be remdied.  Thanks)

Comment: I understand, I'm rather new to this platform, hence the mistake. Do you maybe also know how to address the issue on the database level?